# Add data to text with print_r()

Tags: php

I have a text file and each time a visitor access this page I am doing a print_r() to it.

How can I use print_r() to add data to my `file.txt` text file ? Currently the text is overwritten and stores only last print_r().

```
$output = print_r($data, true);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output);
```

Comment: fopen() in append mode, then fwrite() and fclose()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`FILE_APPEND`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) flag:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

> **FILE_APPEND**   If file filename already exists, append the data to the
>   file instead of overwriting it.

Comment: How is it possible to do a line break? I tried this but it only adds the br tag `file_put_contents('file.txt', $output.'<br>', FILE_APPEND);` ?

Comment: You might want to try a newline `\n` or the PHP end of line constant, `PHP_EOL`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the flag `FILE_APPEND` to append the `$output` at the end of the file.

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

Appending data to the bottom (*end*) of the file.

```
file_put_contents($fileDestination,print_r($data,true),FILE_APPEND)
```

**Method 2:**

Append data to the top (*start*) of the file.

```
$fileDestination = "/path/to/your/file.txt";
$oldData = "";
/***
 Edit some catching if file exists
 ***/
 if(file_exists($fileDestination)){
   $oldData = file_get_contents($fileDestination,false, null, 0);
 }
$saveData = print_r($data,true).PHP_EOL.$oldData;
unset($oldData);
file_put_contents($fileDestination,$saveData);
```

Method 2 Explanation:

get the data from within the file, this data is held in a variable in the order it appears in the file. You then get your `print_r` data and then append a line break to it and add the old file data so that the new data appears at the top of the file, then writing the whole chunk back into the file, overwriting what currently exists there.

`PHP_EOL` is the PHP End of Line character and is used for line breaks.